# How to write a for loop and if statement in this excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been given an excel sheet with thousands of records. Instead of doing it manually, I am thinking of writing a *For Loop* and *If Statement* in VBA but I don't know how.

First, take the `Date_Key` and if it is within the `Start Date` and `End Date`, print the `Current_Month` in `Period`.

Then move to the next `Date_Key` and repeat. But if this `Date_Key` is the same as the previous one and the previous `Current_Month` has been used, go to next set of `Start Date` and `End Date` and if it is within the `Start Date` and `End Date`, use this `Current_Month` and insert it into the `Period`.

Can someone please help me with this? Much appreciated! Thank you very much.

```
                    |------ THIS IS A REFERENCE TABLE ------|
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Period | Date_Key | Current_Month | Start Date | End Date |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 20130914 | 2014 P02      | 20121001   | 20130929 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 20130914 | 2014 P03      | 20121029   | 20131027 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 20130914 | 2014 P04      | 20121203   | 20131201 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 20130926 | 2014 P05      | 20121231   | 20131229 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        | 20130926 | 2014 P06      | 20130128   | 20140126 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result:

```
                    |------ THIS IS A REFERENCE TABLE ------|
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Period | Date_Key | Current_Month | Start Date | End Date |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2014 P02| 20130914 | 2014 P02      | 20121001   | 20130929 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2014 P03| 20130914 | 2014 P03      | 20121029   | 20131027 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2014 P04| 20130914 | 2014 P04      | 20121203   | 20131201 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2014 P02| 20130926 | 2014 P05      | 20121231   | 20131229 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|2014 P03| 20130926 | 2014 P06      | 20130128   | 20140126 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give it a go and show us what you have so far? eg  `Dim i as integer  For i = 0 to sheets.UsedRows   If Range("A1").Value2 = "x" Then ... ElseIf... Else...  End If... Next`

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I am very sorry. I know nothing about VBA. At the time of writing, I am googling and reading some tutorial.

Comment: You might as well add the expected result. It's better than us guessing what the values in `Period` would be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your entire program for you, but if all you want is an example of a simple `For` block and an `If` block:

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    If (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i) = 1) Then
        'do something
    End If
Next
```

I'd suggest learning something about VBA, e.g. via Google.